# How to write average innerQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average, inner-query

[image: Source Data]

From the Image I have same course id and multiple videos for i want to show the overall watched percentage as the average of them how can I do that I want something like this:

```
(SELECT SUM(watched_percentage) FROM tbl_student_learning_path where course_id = 298 
AND SELECT COUNT(watched_percentage) FROM tbl_student_learning_path where course_id = 298)
as overallScore
```

Comment: Normally, the overall watched percentage would be `(SUM(watched_time) / SUM(total_time)) * 100`, or `((45+5)/(93+5)) * 100` or 51.02%, not the average of 48% and 100% or 74%.  The latter is almost totally meaningless as a figure.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @JonathanLeffler, and was going to write something similar as an answer but didn't have time. And now I see a much inferior answer has been accepted!?

Comment: Okay so how can I write can you please write in answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, you'd get a weighted average this way

```
SELECT
    course_id,
    (100 * SUM(watched_total_time) / SUM(video_total_time)) AS WeightedAvg
FROM
    tbl_student_learning_path 
WHERE
    course_id=298
GROUP BY
    course_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT course_id,AVG(watched_percentage) AS Avg
FROM tbl_student_learning_path 
WHERE course_id=298
GROUP BY course_id
```